# MySql is not starting in XAMPP in windows 10

Tags: mysql, xampp

When i am trying to start mysql on xampp server, it is not responding. It has the following error on log file. Any help will be appreciated. Apache Server is running fine though. Thanks

```
2016-06-21 10:49:15 5756 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2016-06-21 10:49:15 150c InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2016-06-21 10:49:15 5756 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2016-06-21 10:49:15 5756 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2016-06-21 10:49:15 5756 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2016-06-21 10:49:15 5756 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2016-06-21 10:49:15 5756 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2016-06-21 10:49:15 5756 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2016-06-21 10:49:15 5756 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2016-06-21 10:49:15 5756 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2016-06-21 10:49:15 5756 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 49463
2016-06-21 10:49:15 5756 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2016-06-21 10:49:15 5756 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2016-06-21 10:49:15 5756 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2016-06-21 10:49:18 5756 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
2016-06-21 10:49:18 5756 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 1600624
2016-06-21 10:49:20 5756 [Note] InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percent: 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
InnoDB: Apply batch completed
2016-06-21 10:49:21 5756 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2016-06-21 10:49:22 5756 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2016-06-21 10:49:22 5756 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.16 started; log sequence number 1600624
2016-06-21 10:49:22 5756 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2016-06-21 10:49:22 5756 [Note] IPv6 is available.

2016-06-21 10:49:22 5756 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';

2016-06-21 10:49:22 5756 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Comment: Then why mysql is not starting?